# Bus error while compiling with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I can't seem to be able to compile even simple C programs anymore; I can't seem to be able to pinpoint what changed from yesterday, when all seemed to be fine.

I'm using `gcc 5.2.1`.

Compiling this program (or any other program)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

gives me this error:

```
<built-in>: internal compiler error: Bus error
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

I'm at loss; what I found while searching on the internet are posts from a few years back detailing bugs that have been solved, or bus error generated from a C program for incorrect use of memory.

I've tried purging and reinstalling gcc with apt-get (I'm using Ubuntu), but nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe reinstall gcc? it looks gcc is corrupted somehow.

Comment: @fluter Already tried with apt-get, added an edit to the post

Comment: Did you make any changes to gcc recently say and upgrade?

Comment: @sjsam I didn't change anything in gcc, at least not voluntarily; I experimented with some warning options (-Werror, -Wextra, -Wall and so on), but as far as I can see doing that should be of no consequence to gcc itself. I haven't updated my system since last week, so I shouldn't have upgraded gcc either. Again, voluntarily at least.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the memory, file system, and disk surface, and maybe did other hardware checks as well.

Comment: `fsck` said everything was fine; I will try with a `memtest` as soon as I'm able to

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with my wireless, too; I have no idea how or why, but after entering the command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and rebooting, `gcc` started working again. I'm confident that this did the trick, as I tried compiling just before issuing the command.

While I'd still like to understand why that happened, I guess this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem I could not install mysqldb and my GCC was giving error like that:

[image]

I fixed the problem in Ubuntu by updater and the Ubuntu partial version

The problem arises because of partial installation of other packages.

Steps:

1) got to updater
  2) find there to update and restart Ubuntu